# Controlling carat vertically with as3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, text, textfield

Earlier I was struggling with moving the Carat horizontally now I need to move it up & down the text field. 
This is for a virtual keyboard so all arrow controls are done with coded buttons.

Heres an example: I have a text field that has two lines with varrying amount of text, and our carat is at the end of the bottom line. My goal is to move the carat up to the end of the first line.

```
var boop = textSelect.text.length;
var snoop = boop;

// arrow controls to move left and right
function larw(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    snoop -=  1;
    stage.focus = textSelect;
    textSelect.setSelection( snoop,snoop);
}

function rarw(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    snoop +=  1;
    stage.focus = textSelect;
    textSelect.setSelection( snoop,snoop);
}

// moving up 
function uarw(event:MouseEvent):void
{

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There may be an easier more elegant way to do this, but this is all I can think of and should be enough to get your started:  (for the moving the caret up)

```
var line:int = textSelect.getLineIndexOfChar(textSelect.caretIndex); //get the current line the caret is in

    //if the line isn't already at the top-most line
if(line > 0){
    var charBounds:Rectangle = textSelect.getCharBoundaries(textSelect.caretIndex); //get the coordinates of the current caret position
    var prevLinePos:Number = charBounds.y - textSelect.getLineMetrics(line-1).leading - (textSelect.getLineMetrics(line-1).height * .5); //the y value of the middle of the previous line

    var newIndex:Number = textSelect.getCharIndexAtPoint(charBounds.x,prevLinePos); //get the character that is closest to that position

    textSelect.setSelection(newIndex,newIndex); //set the caret
}
```